# PowerPoint interop PpSlideLayout to CustomLayout

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop

In my C# app I'm calling presentation.Slides.AddSlide, and the second parameter is showing as CustomLayout.  The only layout I can find is PpSlideLayout, which the compiler says it can't convert to CustomLayout.

What am I supposed to be passing for this second argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument should be a custom layout object.

The object hierarchy looks like this:

```
Presentation
  Designs (collection)
    Design(x)
      SlideMaster
        CustomLayouts (collection)
          CustomLayout(x)
```

So in VBA, you'd do something like:

```
 ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide 1, _
 ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(2)
```

That'd add a new slide 1 based on the second layout in the first design (what we'd call a slide master).  Yes. The object model is a bit twisted.

Comment: Thank you!  That was exactly what I needed.